# Deploy of several contexts of the same application in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

We deploy our product in tomcat and we are having several contexts for it, one for each client. The application is the same, we only change some parameteres in a properties.file to point the database and other specific data.

```
Client1  context1   http://app/context1
Client2  context2   http://app/context2
Client3  context3   http://app/context3
```

So we have several repeated jars, and i want to be able to update the whole instances in batch. What we are doing is keeping the jars in a tomcat classpath so our war just consists of the web.xml, properties and a context.xml and we just deploy them at will. I dont want to have the application jars inside of the war because we are having a lot of changes and we wourld be constantly packeting and eploy everithing again and again.

Will this work? Is this a good practice? Does tomcar have any tool to help us in this situation? How can i make this efficient?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure of the use case for deploying several instances in the same tomcat installation, but this is perfectly valid. If you point the docBase at the same jar, then you can update all of then at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

It will work and is generally a good practice because it is more efficient in terms of memory usage (shared jars are only loaded once). It can be cumbersome in development because it will require restarting tomcat whenever a shared jar is changed, since they are in a common class loader. You should place your jars in a separate directory (not in the tomcat/lib directory) and update catalina.properties to point to that directory:

```
shared.loader=/path/to/your/jars,/path/to/your/jars/*.jar
```